# Cannot Connect to Wifi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi, apt, gui

So to begin, I have a brand new Raspberry Pi 3 B with Raspbian installed from NOOBS. I am trying to connect it to Wi-Fi however the GUI says `No Wireless Interfaces`. When I hop into Terminal, I can see wlan0, but if I use `iwlist wlan0` scan it shows `No scan results`.

Most of the tutorials/forums/answers I have found involve using `apt-get` but I'm not connected to any network as I don't have any Ethernet to connect to and I can't get connected to Wi-Fi. I have tried editing the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file to include the SSID and key but to no avail. I have done the same with the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. I do have access to a separate computer where I can download items onto the microSD, however I cannot share the network for some reason (problem for a different time).

I tried downloading **wicd** onto the microSD and using `sudo python setup.py install` but because there's no network connection it fails to fetch the required files. I also have a USB Wi-Fi adapter but that has the same problems as the built-in Wi-Fi receiver on the RPi 3. I have tried numerous solutions with no real answer. Hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction or show me if I'm missing something.

Comment: This is the best source to follow step by step that I have come across for connecting to WiFi... [raspberry pi WiFi setup](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am not sure where the answer went but the answer that solved this persons problem was to do a fresh install of the OS and then run the WiFi setup as there appeared to be a glitch in the OS.

Comment: I'm not really sure where it went either I thought I had already counted yours as correct... Either way thank you